# Display depending on date (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

So I am not great at Javascript, but I managed to take some examples and then combined them into this:

```
    var date = new Date().getDate();  
    var greeting;

    if (date < 24) {
        greeting = "Nej det är:";
    } else {
        greeting = "Ja!";
        document.getElementById("clockdiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
```

It is supposed to display one greeting on the specified date and if it isn't that date it will display some other thing.

Problems:

1. if the date goes over (in this case 24) it gets all kinds of errors;
2. It only goes by the day and not the month;
3. And some other small errors.

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: If you get error messages, show the exact error message. If the errors are run-time behavior, describe it. I would also recommend spell checking your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of the answers, i combined all of them and came up with the solution. And here it is.
Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/linushg111/o6u8quwz/

```
    var date = new Date();  
   var day = date.getDate();
   var n = date.getMonth();
   var greeting;
    if (day === 24 && n === 11) {
        greeting = "YES";
    } else {
        greeting = "NO :-(";
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understood you meant day of the month.

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tscm02xb/

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();

var greeting;
    if (day < 24) {
        greeting = "Nej det är:";
    } else {
        greeting = "Ja!";
            document.getElementById("clockdiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date().getDate()` returns only the day of the month. You could try this.

```
var date = new Date();  
var greeting;

if ( !(date.getDate === 24 && date.getMonth() === 11) ) {
    greeting = "Nej det är:";
} else {
    greeting = "Ja!";
    document.getElementById("clockdiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
```

Answer (score 1):

that should help:

```
var date = new Date();  
   var day = date.getDate();
   var month = date.getMonth();
   var greeting;
    if (day !== 24) {
        greeting = "Nej det är:";
    } else if (day === 24 && month === 0) { // supposed to be january for example
        greeting = "Ja!";
            document.getElementById("clockdiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
```